# How to show two items per row, android listview

Tags: android, android-listview

I am facing an issue in designing and implementing a layout like: [image]

Can anyone guide me how to add two item per row?

**I have tried gridview but couldn't achieve this perfect design.**

Comment: seems like a custom adapter issue

Comment: See [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-gridview-layout-tutorial/) and [this](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-gridview-example/)

Comment: I have already used gridview but result wasn't same.

Answer (score 1):

Create a list of `Pair<YourObjectType, YourObjectType>` and in your adapter set your views according to pair.first, pair.second objects

Comment: if you can provide little more description.

Comment: I'm assuming that you know how to create a list with an adapter. Pair is a java type that stores two objects. You will put those two objects i a pair object, create an arrayList of those objects and send the list to your adapter and in getView method, you will get the item according to position and you can get those two objects that you need to show in a row by accessing with pair.first and pair.second

Comment: yea, know about all this adapter thing, Pair was new for me. Thanks Indeed.

Comment: mark answer as accepted if this is a solution for you

Answer (score 0):

Actually as it looks you have here 4 items per row: 2 `ImageView`'s and 2 `TextView`'s.
To achive this you need to use a custom `ArrayAdapter` take a look at this answer I gave yesterday on how to create one:

[How to Build ArrayAdapter from result received from webservice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15799814/how-to-build-arrayadapter-from-result-received-from-webservice/15799946#15799946)